# How to understand "Ginny's things second-hand" in this context?

Tags: phrase-usage

> "Well, we'll mange," said Mrs Weasley, but she looked worried. "I expect we'll be able to pick up a lot of **Ginny's things second-hand**."

I think "*pick up*" here means "*to buy*". However, **Ginny's things second-hand** looks odd. Maybe, **second-hand**, as an adjective, is used as a complement? Otherwise, I think it might be better to put it as: ***pick up a lot of things second-hand for Ginny***. Does it make any sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an adverb here:

> adverb
>   On the basis that something has had a previous owner.
>   ‘tips on the pitfalls to avoid when buying second-hand’
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/second-hand)</sub>

It sounds perfectly fine to me. So does your proposed rewrite, which also uses it as an adverb. It means that Mrs. Weasley will be either shopping at the wizarding [Goodwill](http://www.goodwill.org/) or perhaps see if she can get them from her family.

Comment: Do you mean "second-hand" modifies "pick up" as an adverb?

Comment: @dan Yeah that sounds right.

Comment: In my rewriting " pick up a lot of things second-hand for Ginny", I tried to use it as an adjective to modify things but turns out you understand it as an adverb. Interesting.:)

Comment: @dan "For Ginny" is a prepositional phrase that can be moved around or deleted from the sentence without affecting its grammaticality.  If you wanted to use an adjective you'd say "secondhand things"

Comment: Mrs Weasely could also be shopping in a second hand shop, owned by a person that buys second had products and sells them to make a profit. Also in British English we would say a charity shop rather than goodwill.

Answer (score 4):

*Ginny's things* means "things Ginny needs" or "things for Ginny".

To *pick up* is an informal way of saying "purchase" or "buy".

*second-hand*  characterizes the shopping for or the purchase of a pre-owned item.

> When shopping for furniture for their rooms, university students typically shop second-hand.
>
> The university student bought a desk and chair second-hand.

The opposite is "new":

> When shopping for furniture for their rooms, university students typically do not shop new.
>
> Few university students buy their furniture new.

Both can be used adjectivally:

> The university student bought a second-hand desk and chair.
>
> The university student wanted to buy a new desk and chair but settled for second-hand.

Answer (score 1):

I might be misreading your question here but the gist of the sentence is: Mrs Weasley is worried about money but she thinks they will be OK because she thinks they will be able to buy everything they need used or second-hand.